# get value from multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get value from multi array but a lot of arrays there. I am confused. Who can help me?
I need get GROUP_CODE and DESCRIPTION values from result (in foreach) like this :

```
GROUP_CODE 01 DESCRIPTION BLACK
GROUP_CODE 02 DESCRIPTION WHITE
GROUP_CODE 04 DESCRIPTION RED
GROUP_CODE 07 DESCRIPTION BLUE
```

print_r result :

```
Array
(
    [GetGrupResult] => Array
        (
            [Result] => Array
                (
                    [Error] => 
                    [Typ] => OK
                )

            [Set] => Array
                (
                    [schema] => Array
                        (
                            [element] => Array
                                (
                                    [complexType] => Array
                                        (
                                            [choice] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [element] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [complexType] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [sequence] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [element] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [simpleType] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [restriction] => Array
                                                                                                        (
                                                                                                            [maxLength] => Array
                                                                                                                (
                                                                                                                    [!value] => 2
                                                                                                                )

                                                                                                            [!base] => xs:string
                                                                                                        )

                                                                                                )

                                                                                            [!name] => GROUP_CODE
                                                                                        )

                                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [simpleType] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [restriction] => Array
                                                                                                        (
                                                                                                            [maxLength] => Array
                                                                                                                (
                                                                                                                    [!value] => 50
                                                                                                                )

                                                                                                            [!base] => xs:string
                                                                                                        )

                                                                                                )

                                                                                            [!name] => DESCRIPTION
                                                                                            [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [!name] => Table1
                                                        )

                                                    [!minOccurs] => 0
                                                    [!maxOccurs] => unbounded
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [!name] => NewDataSet
                                    [!msdata:IsDataSet] => true
                                    [!msdata:UseCurrentLocale] => true
                                )

                            [!id] => NewDataSet
                        )

                    [diffgram] => Array
                        (
                            [NewDataSet] => Array
                                (
                                    [Table1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [GROUP_CODE] => 01
                                                    [DESCRIPTION] => BLACK
                                                    [!diffgr:id] => Table11
                                                    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 0
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [GROUP_CODE] => 02
                                                    [DESCRIPTION] => WHITE
                                                    [!diffgr:id] => Table12
                                                    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 1
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [GROUP_CODE] => 04
                                                    [DESCRIPTION] => RED
                                                    [!diffgr:id] => Table13
                                                    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 2
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [GROUP_CODE] => 07
                                                    [DESCRIPTION] => BLUE
                                                    [!diffgr:id] => Table14
                                                    [!msdata:rowOrder] => 3
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

var_dump result

```
array(1) {
  ["GetGrupResult"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Result"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Error"]=>
      NULL
      ["Typ"]=>
      string(2) "OK"
    }
    ["Set"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["schema"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["element"]=>
        array(4) {
          ["complexType"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["choice"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["element"]=>
              array(2) {
                ["complexType"]=>
                array(1) {
                  ["sequence"]=>
                  array(1) {
                    ["element"]=>
                    array(2) {
                      [0]=>
                      array(2) {
                        ["simpleType"]=>
                        array(1) {
                          ["restriction"]=>
                          array(2) {
                            ["maxLength"]=>
                            array(1) {
                              ["!value"]=>
                              string(1) "2"
                            }
                            ["!base"]=>
                            string(9) "xs:string"
                          }
                        }
                        ["!name"]=>
                        string(10) "GROUP_CODE"
                      }
                      [1]=>
                      array(3) {
                        ["simpleType"]=>
                        array(1) {
                          ["restriction"]=>
                          array(2) {
                            ["maxLength"]=>
                            array(1) {
                              ["!value"]=>
                              string(2) "50"
                            }
                            ["!base"]=>
                            string(9) "xs:string"
                          }
                        }
                        ["!name"]=>
                        string(11) "DESCRIPTION"
                        ["!minOccurs"]=>
                        string(1) "0"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                ["!name"]=>
                string(6) "Table1"
              }
              ["!minOccurs"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["!maxOccurs"]=>
              string(9) "unbounded"
            }
          }
          ["!name"]=>
          string(10) "NewDataSet"
          ["!msdata:IsDataSet"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["!msdata:UseCurrentLocale"]=>
          string(4) "true"
        }
        ["!id"]=>
        string(10) "NewDataSet"
      }
      ["diffgram"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["NewDataSet"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["Table1"]=>
          array(4) {
            [0]=>
            array(4) {
              ["GROUP_CODE"]=>
              string(2) "01"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(3) "BLACK"
              ["!diffgr:id"]=>
              string(7) "Table11"
              ["!msdata:rowOrder"]=>
              string(1) "0"
            }
            [1]=>
            array(4) {
              ["GROUP_CODE"]=>
              string(2) "02"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(6) "WHITE"
              ["!diffgr:id"]=>
              string(7) "Table12"
              ["!msdata:rowOrder"]=>
              string(1) "1"
            }
            [2]=>
            array(4) {
              ["GROUP_CODE"]=>
              string(2) "04"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(15) "RED"
              ["!diffgr:id"]=>
              string(7) "Table13"
              ["!msdata:rowOrder"]=>
              string(1) "2"
            }
            [3]=>
            array(4) {
              ["GROUP_CODE"]=>
              string(2) "07"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(3) "BLUE"
              ["!diffgr:id"]=>
              string(7) "Table14"
              ["!msdata:rowOrder"]=>
              string(1) "3"
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe, but don't quote me... `foreach ($array["GetGrupResult"]["Set"]["diffgram"]["NewDataSet"]["Table1"][0] as $elem) { print $elem['GROUP_CODE'].'  '.$elem['DESCRIPTION']; }`

Comment: miiiight be.... `["GetGrupResult"]["Set"]["schema"]["diffgram"]["NewDataSet"]["Table1"][0]`

Comment: I think it took everyone the same time to figure out and write the long-@$$ array! But everyone seems to have the same answer...except I think not the `["schema"]`...though maybe...it's making me think twice here. I'm gonna stick with what I got.

Comment: it's a really messy array... that's for sure.  especially for someone who can't traverse an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...I think it's the right one. This is quite the array!:

```
<?php
    $data = $array['GetGrupResult']['Set']['diffgram']['NewDataSet']['Table1'];

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            print_r($value);
        } ?>
```